# How to use the automatic invocation of ndk-build in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

In the newer versions of Android Studio, we can build .cpp and .c files in the /jni folder without any android.mk file. This is accomplished by simply placing something like the following lines in our build.gradle file:

```
defaultConfig {
        ..

        ndk {
            moduleName "niceprocess"
            cFlags "-std=c++11 -fexceptions"
            ldLibs "log"
            stl "gnustl_shared"
            abiFilter "armeabi-v7a"
        }
    }
}
```

This seems to recursively build everything in the jni folder it finds and places it in the 'niceprocess' module.

My main question is - is there a way to control what modules will be built with which files, and build multiple modules, each with different cFlags, and be able to #include headers from one module in another.

I know this can all be accomplished with an an android.mk, but I am wondering if it is possible yet with the gradle system.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there's no way to control what modules will be built with which files as well as many other things. As of now, gradle plug-in for Android Studio support only one very basic case for NDK builds - just one module without any dependencies, compiled completely from the set of source files located in 'jni' folder.

You can assess it on your own - just look into [NdkOptions.java](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/build-system/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/internal/dsl/NdkOptions.java) and [NdkCompile.groovy](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/tools/base/+/master/build-system/gradle/src/main/groovy/com/android/build/gradle/tasks/NdkCompile.groovy). In first file, you can see that the only options supported for NDK in gradle script are 'moduleName', 'cFlags', 'ldLibs', 'stl' and 'abiFilters'. In second file, you can see how Android.mk generated using that options, without any chance to customize it more than that options allow.

If you need more smart control of native sources build, you need disable NDK support in gradle script and use explicit call of ndk-build. This way you need specify set of source files in Android.mk manually after adding them into source tree in Android Studio, which is not so convenient, but you'll have more control of modules, its dependencies, its build options etc.

Comment: Has this changed? I was trying to manage which ABI was built with Gradle inside Android studio.